# MongoDB "Starting new replica set monitor for" message meaning

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

I have a `MongoDB (4.0.4)` replica set with 3 members.

The system works well, but the logs are full of the following message:

> NETWORK  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Starting new replica set
>   monitor for

The message is logged every 5 minutes and repeated 4 times each time.

1. Why does MongoDB needs to start a replica set monitor so often?
2. Is this normal or is it a sign of an issue with my configuration?

Answer (score 3):

The Starting new replica set monitor message is informative, and is mainly used for troubleshooting purposes. You can safely ignore these lines.To provide high availability, each replica set member needs to monitor other members to know each other’s status. This is to determine if part of the replica set is not accessible, and whether an election should be called.
http://mongodb.2344371.n4.nabble.com/Starting-new-replica-set-monitor-for-message-meaning-td23167.html